# Twitter Bootstrap 3.3.4 carousel images not working when displaying from local file in safari 7.1.3

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, carousel

Twitter Bootstrap 3.3.4 carousel images not loading when it is from local file or folder in safari 7.1.3 why is that. When i try to use images from browser location then it displays images. Where as in my case i want to load images in carousel from local file/folder.

i am including everything like

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 //EN">
<script src="js/bootstrap-carousel.js"></script>
<!-- jQuery (necessary for Bootstrap's JavaScript plugins) -->
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<img src="image/1.jpg"> <!--this is how i am using img tag in html to display from local file-->
```

EDIT:-

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>

<head>

<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<meta name="description" content="">
<meta name="author" content="">

<title>Modern Business - Start Bootstrap Template</title>

<!-- Bootstrap Core CSS -->
<link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

<!-- Custom CSS -->
<link href="css/modern-business.css" rel="stylesheet">

<!-- Custom Fonts -->
<link href="font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">

<!-- HTML5 Shim and Respond.js IE8 support of HTML5 elements and media queries -->
<!-- WARNING: Respond.js doesn't work if you view the page via file:// -->
<!--[if lt IE 9]>
    <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/libs/html5shiv/3.7.0/html5shiv.js"></script>
    <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/libs/respond.js/1.4.2/respond.min.js"></script>
    <!-- jQuery (necessary for Bootstrap's JavaScript plugins) -->
 <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/bootstrap-carousel.js"></script>    <![endif]-->

</head>

<body>

<!-- Navigation -->
<nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top" role="navigation">
    <div class="container">
        <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
        <div class="navbar-header">
            <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
                <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            </button>
            <a class="navbar-brand" href="index.html">Start Bootstrap</a>
        </div>
        <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                <li>
                    <a href="about.html">About</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="services.html">Services</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="contact.html">Contact</a>
                </li>
                <li class="dropdown">
                    <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Portfolio <b class="caret"></b></a>
                    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                        <li>
                            <a href="portfolio-1-col.html">1 Column Portfolio</a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="portfolio-2-col.html">2 Column Portfolio</a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="portfolio-3-col.html">3 Column Portfolio</a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="portfolio-4-col.html">4 Column Portfolio</a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="portfolio-item.html">Single Portfolio Item</a>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li class="dropdown">
                    <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Blog <b class="caret"></b></a>
                    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                        <li>
                            <a href="blog-home-1.html">Blog Home 1</a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="blog-home-2.html">Blog Home 2</a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="blog-post.html">Blog Post</a>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li class="dropdown">
                    <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Other Pages <b class="caret"></b></a>
                    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                        <li>
                            <a href="full-width.html">Full Width Page</a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="sidebar.html">Sidebar Page</a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="faq.html">FAQ</a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="404.html">404</a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="pricing.html">Pricing Table</a>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
    </div>
    <!-- /.container -->
</nav>

<!-- Header Carousel -->
<header id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide">
    <!-- Indicators -->
    <ol class="carousel-indicators">
        <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
        <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="1"></li>
        <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="2"></li>
    </ol>

    <!-- Wrapper for slides -->
    <div class="carousel-inner">
        <div class="item active">
            <img src=“image/hampster%20on%20rope.jpg”>
            <div class="carousel-caption">
                <h2>Caption 1</h2>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="item">
            <img src=“image/hampster%20on%20rope.jpg">
            <div class="carousel-caption">
                <h2>Caption 2</h2>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="item">
            <img src=“image/hampster%20on%20rope.jpg">
            <div class="carousel-caption">
                <h2>Caption 3</h2>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <!-- Controls -->
    <a class="left carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="prev">
        <span class="icon-prev"></span>
    </a>
    <a class="right carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="next">
        <span class="icon-next"></span>
    </a>
</header>
```

![project file order](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QyUdX.png)

Any help will be really appreciated.

Thanks a lot.

Comment: put the jquery library first then bootstrap carousel library after that

Comment: And also used html5 doctype `<!DOCTYPE html>`

Comment: create a jsfiddle or put html code for carousel

Comment: but how to display local file image in jsfiddle because images from browser in jsfiddle working

Comment: Then put the html code in your question

Comment: please check it i just posted html code in my post

Comment: ok the image name has space. encode the src.  try it like `hampster%20on%20rope.jpg`

Comment: i fixed that but still not displaying image

Comment: is any error in browser console.

Comment: it shows blue image icon for not finding image when path and image name is correct

Comment: Somewhat it may folder permission problem in mac OS.

Comment: This is the image folder i added in modern business zip file in which image is

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/74484/discussion-between-tamil-selvan-and-user1120133).

Comment: how to solve this issue. ok we can discuss this issue

Comment: You are right. i don't know how to thank you. really really appreciate so much for your help. Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Load a jquery library first and then  bootstrap-carousel.js file because  bootstrap-carousel.js depend on jquery library

And also used **html5 doctype**

try

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<!-- jQuery (necessary for Bootstrap's JavaScript plugins) -->
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/bootstrap-carousel.js"></script>
```

**Edit:**
Quote symbol is different

Replace this

```
   <img src=“image/hampster%20on%20rope.jpg”>
```

to

```
<img src="image/hampster%20on%20rope.jpg">
```

Comment: i just corrected the order and tried it but still not working.

Comment: And also used html5 doctype `<!DOCTYPE html>`

Comment: <!-- Bootstrap Core CSS -->
    <link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="css/modern-business.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
        <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/libs/html5shiv/3.7.0/html5shiv.js"></script>
        <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/libs/respond.js/1.4.2/respond.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/bootstrap-carousel.js"></script>

Comment: this is how i am adding